# I would like to add some code into my Google Sheet. When I enter a number a url should be created

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

It's simple but I am new to Google Sheets.

I enter a number in a field in a row. See img below.

When the number is entered I want it to turn into a hyperlink so it clickible.

Web Address example....http://idx.domain.com/details.asp?mls=77777777&aid=BB333833 Everything remains same. all thing that changes is the 77777777 (A2, A3, A4)

Comment: See _what_ img below? Do you want a spreadsheet formula? Or a script? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints, then edit your question to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onEdit()** trigger. Set up an **if** statement, so that if the first column is edited change it's value to

`"=http://idx.domain.com/details.asp?mls=" + your cell value + "&aid=BB333833"`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112175/2589810) is a similar question with an **onEdit()** trigger

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30232201/2589810) is another example which shows how to check for the correct column.

There are plenty of similar question on this topic in SO if you do some searching.